# Finding the index

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an odd number and even numbers in a given string, and the return value should be an index of the odd number or even number.
for example

```js
 oddOrEvenValue('2 4 9 6 10'); // => should return 3 as an index of odd number in the string
 oddOrEvenValue('1 4 5 11'); // => should return 2 as an index of even number in the string
```

This is my code

```
 const oddOrEvenValue = str => {
  //convert the string into an array
  let strToArr = str.split(' ');
  //filtering the Even numbers
  const evenNumbers = strToArr.filter(e => e % 2 === 0);
  //filtering Odd numbers
  const oddNumbers = strToArr.filter(od => od % 2 !== 0);
  //comparing the even and odd arrays
  if(Number(evenNumbers.length) > Number(oddNumbers.length)) {
    return oddNumbers;
  } else {
    return evenNumbers;
  }
}

console.log(oddOrEvenValue('2 4 9 6 10')); // => 3 is the index of an odd number
```

so i'm wondering how to get the index of an odd number instead of getting the the number itself?

```js
const oddOrEvenValue = str => {
  //convert the string into an array
  let strToArr = str.split(' ');
  //filtering the Even numbers
  const evenNumbers = strToArr.filter(e => e % 2 === 0);
  //filtering Odd numbers
  const oddNumbers = strToArr.filter(od => od % 2 !== 0);
  //comparing the even and odd arrays
  if(Number(evenNumbers.length) > Number(oddNumbers.length)) {
    return oddNumbers;
  } else {
    return evenNumbers;
  }
}

console.log(oddOrEvenValue('2 4 9 6 10'));
```

Comment: `oddOrEvenValue('2 4 9 6 10');` should return 2 or 3? You mention 3 but the odd number's index is 2 as it starts with 0.

Comment: Hi @Zsolt Meszaros, it should start at 1 instead of 0

Comment: **Indexes start at 0** not at 1. *Positions* start at .... well, 1st

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, yes, i know the index starts at 0 but I want it to start at 1

Comment: And what if the input is `'2 4 1 3'`? Which value should it return?

Comment: @FZs, the input should have one odd value or one even value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `indexOf` array method.

```js
const oddOrEvenIndex = str => {
  //convert the string into an array
  let strToArr = str.split(' ');
  //filtering the Even numbers
  const evenNumbers = strToArr.filter(e => e % 2 === 0);
  //filtering Odd numbers
  const oddNumbers = strToArr.filter(od => od % 2 !== 0);
  //comparing the even and odd arrays
  if(evenNumbers.length > oddNumbers.length) {
    return strToArr.indexOf(oddNumbers[0]);
  } else {
    return strToArr.indexOf(evenNumbers[0]);
  }
}

console.log(oddOrEvenIndex('2 4 9 6 10'));
console.log(oddOrEvenIndex('1 4 5 11'));
```

The `length` property is always a number, there's no need to convert it with the `Number()` function.

Also, array indexes start from `0`. If you want the result to be 1-based, add `+ 1` to the `return` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the whole array, check if value is odd or even, then store the index of that value into `evenNumberIndexes`/ `oddNumberIndexes` accordingly.

```js
const oddOrEvenIndex = str => {
  //convert the string into an array
  let strToArr = str.split(' ');
  let evenNumberIndexes = [];
  let oddNumberIndexes = [];

  // iterate over array
  for (var i = 0; i < strToArr.length; i = i + 1) {
      // CHeck if number is odd or even and add the index to the arrays accordingly
      if (strToArr[i] % 2 ==0) {
          evenNumberIndexes.push(i+1);
      } else {
          oddNumberIndexes.push(i+1);
      }
  }
  // comparing the even and odd arrays
  if(Number(evenNumberIndexes.length) > Number(oddNumberIndexes.length)) {
    return oddNumberIndexes;
  } else {
    return evenNumberIndexes;
  }
}
console.log(oddOrEvenIndex('2 4 9 6 10'));
console.log(oddOrEvenIndex('1 4 5 11'));
console.log(oddOrEvenIndex('2 4 9 6 10 8 9 9 6 6'));
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the `length` using `Number` as it's already a number.